# Unable to sum task actuals using VersionOne Python SDK

Tags: python, rest, versionone

Using the Python SDK for VersionOne, I'm trying to sum the actuals for each task.  Here's my best guess at how to do this.

```
term="Actuals:Actual.Value.@Sum"

for task in v1.Task.select("Name",term).filter("AssetState!='Dead'"):
    print(task.Name,task.data[term])
```

First, the `task.data[term]` bit is based on the docs, but there's no such key.  The closest key in the returned task is `"Actuals:Actual"`.

Second, using that as the key instead seems to work for tasks that have no actuals, although instead of "0", I get an empty string.

Finally, once I hit a task with some actuals, I get an `AttributeError` in `v1pysdk.v1meta.add_attribute_to_output()`, which is somehow using `"6"` (the *actual* actual) as a `base_asset`, calling its `with_data()` method.

I'm able to get these sums using, e.g.,

```
<server-base>/rest-1.v1/Data/Task/1234/Actuals:Actual.Value.@Sum
```

so surely I'm close.  Is there a way to do this with the Python SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now. Please update your copy of the SDK.

https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.Python/commit/be721a61e61dee297271e565f27ac7ba5a788a7a